# Unable to access API due to authorisation

Tags: java, spring-security, jhipster

I created my own api to serve the UI with data when requested. However I am using JHipster which implements Spring Security to authenticate api requests. When I am logged into the application and directly access the api using the url (localhost:9090/api/lesson) it gives me a 401 for both my user and admin roles.

```
{
  "type" : "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title" : "Unauthorized",
  "status" : 401,
  "detail" : "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
  "path" : "/api/lesson",
  "message" : "error.http.401"
}
```

I checked the security config and the path /api/** has be set to authenticated which is what baffles me why if logged in I cannot access the resource.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
        .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
    .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .disable()
    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("api/lesson").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/profile-info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
    .and()
        .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());

}
```

Although my API isn't created like JHipsters, like the use of CrudRepository instead of JPA, I didn't think this would be an issue. However, I may be wrong.

```
@RequestMapping("api/lesson")
@RestController
public class LessonAPI {

    private final LessonService service;

    public LessonAPI(@Autowired LessonService service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Lesson> getAllLessons() {
        return service.getAllLessons();
    }

}
```

Comment: `.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()` believe this will override the permitall defined before it, may want to correct the slash too

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Not entirely sure what you mean by correcting the slash? The other api's work fine e.g /api/profile-info.

Comment: you have `.antMatchers("api/lesson").permitAll()` instead of `.antMatchers("/api/lesson").permitAll()`

Comment: Still unauthorised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are not using like following:

```
http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**","/api/user/exist")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**", "/api/gift/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line and all your /api/* resources will be public.

```
.antMatchers("/api/test/**", "/api/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
```